# Postgres which type of index to use for varchar search by prefix

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing

For a postgres varchar column that I would very frequently search by prefix, what type of index should I be using?

```
select * from customer.customers where name like 'James%'
```

My table is something like

```
James Bond
James Blond
James Sunderland
David Copperfield
David Beckham
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a B-tree index with an operator class that supports pattern matching:

```
CREATE INDEX ON customer.customers (name text_pattern_ops);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query is fine.  You can even use a regular index on it:

```
create index idx_customer_name on customer(name);
```

This works because `like` will use a b-tree index when the pattern does not start with wildcards.  For more general patterns, you need a GIST or GIN index.

Comment: But unless his collation is "c", the index needs to be declared with text_pattern_ops